# Parse current cell contents into URL based on the content of the same cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to parse the content of a cell into a URL based on the entered content of the same cell in Google Sheets.  I need the entire column to be processed.

Right now I can only accomplish this with two columns like this...
Column A has an ID number.  Column B uses an array to parse a URL based on the ID number in Column A.  The array formula I'm using in B2 is...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("http://www.website.com/content/"&B3:B, ""&B3:B))
```

So A3 might have the ID number entry: 216856

And this creates the URL in B3: http://www.website.com/content/216856

But what I would really love, is a way to do this with one column.  Perhaps through a script?  Can anyone help me with this, please?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you highlight the column you want to transform then go to edit and choose the find and replace functionality or press `command` `shift` and `H` it will also pop up - then in the `find` field enter: `^` and in the replace field enter `http://www.website.com/content/` and check the `search using regular expressions` checkbox.

Once you click `replace all`, it will add that part of the url to the beginning of all the cells thus turning it into a URL for you. Super easy and generally pretty quick depending on how many rows you have - I have done this with tens of thousands of rows and more.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply.  I missed it somehow.  Thank you for your help.  I was hoping more for a way for it to happen in real time automatically so that when anyone else working on the spreadsheet adds the ID number, it would auto-parse it without any further work on their part.

Comment: Yeah u can probably do an on edit script that will regex replace it